# Firefox + jssh build

Tags: firefox, build, jssh

Has anyone been able to get anything past 4.0b1 of firefox either nightly or releases to build with jssh enabled in the .mozconfig, I get the error .js component without matching .manifest and if I change the rules I get a missing header file, which if I manually copy to the jssh directory and then build gives many many compile errors, was wondering if anyone knew what was going on with jssh as I managed to build it for 4.0b1 and it worked fine (except for an issue involving td tags and events within those tags). I just hope mozilla doesn't discontinue jssh. Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about compiling with jssh, but can't you use the Firefox jssh plugin?

Comment: the problem is that jssh only works for a specified version of FF so the plugin built for FF 3.6 or 4.0b1 will not work for 4.0b2 or 4.0b3 so I need to build the plugin with the browser in order for it to work as it requires some API calls from the browser code to function so it can't be built independently either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looks like it is known, but may not be fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586869).

Comment: Yeah I had seen this before but I was hoping that this wasn't the case

Answer (score 3):

for JSSH users, 
we have created a solution over MozRelp that simulates JSSH.
It's also very fast, since it execute JS on the fly and avoid execute it from a HD File.

Downloadable extension: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/abstracta/WatiN/mozrepl-jsshv2.6.xpi
Source: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mozrepl-jssh

regards, 
Fabián Baptista

Comment: Update: the MozRepl JSSH is broken right now since Firefox 45 and higher requires a signed .xpi, working on it.

Comment: it is done, reach us at www.abstracta.us/contact-us/ if you want to use it.