# Has anyone successfully run a WatiN test against FireFox 4?

Tags: watin, firefox4, jssh

It looks like the jssh plugin (required to run WatiN) still needs work going by FireFox [Bug 586869](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586869), to quote:

> Probably obvious to anyone who ought
>   to be trying to maintain jssh, but, to
>   get it back all you have to do is "hg
>   up -r 3ca5d6674feb" and copy it to
>   wherever you're going to work on it.

Haven't found much [recent activity on SO for jssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jssh) either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firefox + jssh build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496925/firefox-jssh-build)

[WatiN - Support for firefox and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013303/watin-support-for-firefox-and-chrome/17040458#17040458)

check the links - watin works with firefox latest version after installing mozrepl-jsshv2.6.xpi provided by Fabian

Thanks to Fabian. I hope the Watin and Firewatir community embeds this xpi in their repo

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll accept when I get the chance to apply and verify this