# WatiN - Support for firefox and chrome

Tags: watin

Does anyone know if there is any plan to support latter versions of firefox (> 3.6) by WatiN?
As currently i feel it only supports all version of IE.
It only supports Firefox 2.x - 3.6 (http://watin.org/documentation/setting-up-firefox/)

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be best to use selenium webdriver since they update their code everytime firefox updates their browser. Watin last updated in 2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a recent post on the WatiN forum (sorry no link) Jeroen (WatiN conceptor) suggested to make WatiN compatible with FireFox (or other browser) using Selenium's web-driver.

The problem come from the JSSH plugin, that WatiN depend on to control FireFox, that is currently not support/compatible for version of FireFox > 3.6.

But there's no commitement on when this would be done, if done at all.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution working with the jssh new plugin called as [mozrepl-jssh](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mozrepl-jssh/mozrepl-jsshv2.6.xpi)! plugin.
It works fine with the FF 17 ESR version I was able to do the tests.

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using WatiN.Core;
using WatiN.Core.Logging;
using System;

namespace TestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class FFTestJssh
    {

        private static FireFox ff = new FireFox("www.google.co.in");
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add test logic here
            //
            ff.GoTo("http://machine/loginpage");
            ff.TextField(Find.ByName("login_name")).TypeText("Test");
            ff.TextField(Find.ByName("login_password")).TypeText("Secret");
            try
            {
                ff.Button(Find.ByText("Login")).Click();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException te)
            {
                var str = te.Message;
                Logger.LogAction("Time out happened" + str);
            }

            ff.WaitForComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

The only issue I am facing is that click on the login button is giving `TimeOutException` if the page is not loaded properly.
Hope this is helpful to someone who wants that WATiN should work on Firefox latest version.

Regards,
Rahoolm